Only concrete types such as structs, enums and classes can conform to protocols
I have below code with the error as below:

The code is:
protocol BaseFooProtocol {
    var foo: String { get }
}

protocol FooProtocol: BaseFooProtocol {
    var foo: String { get }
    var bar: String { get }
}

struct Foo<T: BaseFooProtocol> {

    func action(foo: T) {
        print(foo.foo)
    }
}

func test() {
    let foo: Foo<FooProtocol> = .init() //The error is here.
}

What I want to achieve is any type conform sub protocol of BaseFooProtocol can be used in a Foo type as generic type. How to code to achieve it?

This appears to be a duplicate of Can't use a protocol as generic argument in swift which was closed as a duplicate of Protocol doesn't conform to itself?.

you can use FooProtocol as a generic constraint but also need it to conform to BaseFooProtocol, you can create a type-erased wrapper to encapsulate FooProtocol.
import Foundation

protocol BaseFooProtocol {
    var foo: String { get }
    var bar: String { get }
}

protocol FooProtocol {
    var foo: String { get }
    var bar: String { get }
}

struct AnyFoo: BaseFooProtocol {
    let foo: String
    let bar: String

    init<T: FooProtocol>(_ foo: T) {
        self.foo = foo.foo
        self.bar = foo.bar
    }
}

struct Foo<T: BaseFooProtocol> {
    func action(foo: T) {
        print(foo.foo)
    }
}

func test() {
    let foo: Foo<AnyFoo> = .init()
    let exampleFoo = AnyFoo(FooExample(foo: "ExampleFoo", bar: "ExampleBar"))
    foo.action(foo: exampleFoo)
}

// Example conforming type
struct FooExample: FooProtocol {
    var foo: String
    var bar: String
}

